# mongoose model.save() return TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

In my nestjs project I'm using mongoose and getting `TypeError: callback is not a function` while I'm trying to model.save().

```
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^1.2.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.2",
"mongoose": "^6.2.6",
```

In my `tags.service.ts` for storing data I have this function:

```
async create(createTagDto: CreateTagDto): Promise<Tag> {
   return await new this.tagModel(createTagDto).save();
}
```

According to [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) by saving a document this should return a Promise.

In my `tags.controller.ts` I define endpoint by calling service function above by:

```
@Post()
async create(@Body() createTagDto: CreateTagDto) {
    return await this.tagsService.create(createTagDto);
}
```

Trying to post data to the endpoint, the new document is created in the database but the server return `Internal server error` with status code 500. The only description in the console is above mentioned `TypeError: callback is not a function` somewhere in `node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js:137:14`.

Does anyone experienced such an issue?

Comment: What does the `tagModel` method look like? The `new` on `new this.tagModel(createTagDto)` makes me wonder if it doesn't return a document, but instead something else with a `save` method (which then calls Mongoose's `save` but in a different way).

Comment: `tagModel` is imported Model from mongoose `import { Model } from 'mongoose';` and injected in a service constructor as such `constructor(@InjectModel(Tag.name) private tagModel: Model<TagDocument>) {}`

Comment: It seems that the line `app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)))` in the project `main.ts` file cause this error. I will explore more the reasons and answer the question with more detailed description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above mentioned error was caused by using nestjs global interceptor `app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)))` in the main.ts bootstrap function. However the build-in ClassSerializerInterceptor cannot figure out a returned mongo Document, a custom interceptor have to be used to properly serialize returned data.

Comment: Could you share some more details of how your custom interceptor properly serialized the mongo document to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
return await new this.tagModel(createTagDto).save();
```

to this

```
const tag = await new this.tagModel.create(createTagDto);
return tag.save();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same result `TypeError: callback is not a function` in `node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js:137:14`. Would it be a bug in mongoose statemachine.js? It seems that the callback is declared as an array and trying to use it as an function... `let states = [...arguments]; const callback = states.pop();` ... `return callback(path, i, paths);`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it benefits anybody else, in my case `MongooseClassSerializerInterceptor` was causing this issue. Simple code:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor(Res))
@Post() {
  return "test"
}
```

Using Nest.js.